# Force IDE: Unable to deploy package to server - Problem: Error parsing file: Element

Tags: deployment, error, error-messages, force.com-ide, deployment-api

I am trying to mass create fields on the account object but whenever I try to deploy the fields I created to the server I get the following error.

If you guys have any thoughts about what could be preventing my xml code from working please let me know.

All of my XML code: https://shrib.com/see/Vvgoeq1KVIdbNLOywQGM4PKruQAU2guOSQ2w7u7S2buGm84ZPB?v=nc

```
*** Deployment Log ***
Result: FAILED
Date: February 21, 2017 11:38:29 PM PST

# Deployed From:
Project name: Offrbox Project
Username: sales@offrbox.com.offrbox
Endpoint: test.salesforce.com

# Deployed To:
Username: sales@offrbox.com.offrbox
Endpoint: test.salesforce.com

# Deploy Results:
File Name:    objects/Account.object
Full Name:  Account
Action:  NO ACTION
Result:  FAILED
Problem: Error parsing file: Element     

{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}defaultValue invalid at this       
location in type CustomObject

File Name:    package.xml
Full Name:  package.xml
Action:  UPDATED
Result:  SUCCESS
Problem: n/a

# Test Results:
n/a
```

Here is what the beginning of the xml code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<fields>
    <fullName>Air_Rights__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Air Rights</label>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Checkbox</type>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>AnnualRevenue</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Bank__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Bank</label>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Checkbox</type>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>Community_Facilities_churches_public_typ__c</fullName>
    <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Community Facilities/churches/public typ</label>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>Checkbox</type>
</fields>
```

There is much more after this

has < /CustomObject > field at the end

Here is all my code in its entirety: https://shrib.com/see/Vvgoeq1KVIdbNLOywQGM4PKruQAU2guOSQ2w7u7S2buGm84ZPB?v=nc

Comment: At what point did you get the error? One of your fields either does not have a default value or there is something wrong with your XML like an unclosed tag or something

Comment: It might help if you post the whole thing. I just deployed the fields you have listed here and didn't have a problem.

Comment: Run the file through an XML validator such as https://www.xmlvalidation.com/. If you can't find the problem like that or through inspection, one strategy is to comment out the first or second half of the fields to find which half of the fields the problem is in and then divide that half in turn and so on.

Comment: I tried running the file through the xml validator xmlvalidation.com but did not receive any errors.

Comment: Here is all my XML code: https://shrib.com/see/Vvgoeq1KVIdbNLOywQGM4PKruQAU2guOSQ2w7u7S2buGm84ZPB?v=nc

Comment: What is the API version of the Package XML <version>38.0</version>, the API version of the ant migration tool JAR file (if you are using ANT) and the API version of the target org.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were missing a `<fields>` tag:

```
@@ -344,6 +344,7 @@
 <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
 <type>Picklist</type>
 </fields>
+<fields>
 <fullName>Joint_Venture__c</fullName>
 <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
 <externalId>false</externalId>
```